# Stored salted token and token comparison

Tags: python, django

I'm generating an url composed of a single use token, and sending it to a user by e-mail. The user should click this link and be redirected to a page which will validate the token and do some actions.

On the database side, I'm storing this token (hashed and salted, for security reasons). The problem is I'm having some difficulties to validate the the token because, the way I'm storing it, I cannot generate the same salt for the same token. And, therefore, I cannot compare this salt with the ones I have stored.

```
# Retrieving or creating object usertokens
usr, created = UserToken.objects.get_or_create(email=email)
# Adding a new token
token = uuid.uuid4().hex
usr.token = make_password(token) # Stores in the local database the salted and hashed token
usr.save()
```

This make_password method I'm using is defined in `django.contrib.auth.hashers`.

By using this method, I cannot generate two times the same salt from the same token.

```
>>> token = 'test'
>>> enc_token1 = make_password(token)
>>> enc_token2 = make_password(token)
>>> enc_token1 == enc_token2
False
```

This, however, does not help me to retrieve from my database the entry corresponding to the token and I cannot validate it.

Comment: Now there's something I've never heard before; _Hashed and salted tokens_. Would you like some ketchup with those tokens?.....</joking>

Comment: All jokes aside, the purpose of hashing and salting is that the original password cannot be acquired from the hashed string. With passwords that's a concern because passwords are often reused in some way, and you want them to remain secret even long after a potential breach. Tokens can simply be reset, and then the attacker will have absolutely no use for the tokens that were acquired. As you've noticed, there's no efficient way to query for a salted and hashed token. That's why tokens are usually stored as plain-text. For what specific security reasons do you want to store them hashed?

Answer (score 1):

Using a simple string equality check of two hashed and salted tokens will not work. The [Django docs for password management](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/passwords/#django.contrib.auth.hashers.check_password) offer a very simple method in the `django.contrib.auth.hashers` namespace that handles all of this for you:

```
>>> token = 'test'
>>> enc_token1 = make_password(token)
>>> check_password('test', enc_token1)
True
```

The `check_password` method does a few things behind the hood, like check if the hashing algorithm has changed. It returns the result of the `verify` method of an algorithm that implements the `BasePasswordHasher` baseclass. Here's an example of an implementation from the [source of the `PBKDF2PasswordHasher`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/_modules/django/contrib/auth/hashers/#check_password):

```
def verify(self, password, encoded):
    algorithm, iterations, salt, hash = encoded.split('$', 3)
    assert algorithm == self.algorithm
    encoded_2 = self.encode(password, salt, int(iterations))
    return constant_time_compare(encoded, encoded_2)
```

Note how the salt is found by splitting the encoded_string on '$', since the [Django docs note](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/passwords/#how-django-stores-passwords) that

> The password attribute of a User object is a string in this format:
>
> ```
> <algorithm>$<iterations>$<salt>$<hash>
> ```

Comment: thanks for answering. The problem of using check_password is because I must know both the encoded string and the token. In my case, my input is the token, and I store many encoded strings in my database. Forgive me if I'm wrong, but, if I use check_password method, it seems I should perform pairwise comparison between the token and all the stored encoded strings. Maybe it will be costly.

Comment: Remember that a hashing algorithm is one-way by its very nature. If you are verifying hashes without knowing the original string, then you are pretty much defeating the purpose of a hash in the first-place, which is to prevent an attacker who has the hashes from knowing the plain text.